# How to call or invoke Salesforce apex controller from an external URL

Tags: web

We have a need in our company for our website to pass a string of data to Salesforce. This string of data will then be used to initiate some processes in Salesforce.
Does anyone have an example of a URL that can be passed to Salesforce along with some data that will cause Salesforce to run a custom controller.

If the custom controller is called ActionWebCall what would the URL look like and can an example of the controller code that receives that URL/data string be provided, even if its just to say 'hello world'.  I can then take things from there.

At this point Salesforce does not need to return info back to the web.

@Sander de Jong - My specific problem was how to get a data string into SF from an external website.  I did google this and there is lots on how to get SF to send data out but few hits on how to get data in.  I did peruse the doco re APIS & REST APIs, Web services etc.  I just wanted to find someone that said 'I did this **specific** thing' & it worked along with an example.  The link that Ratan provided was enough, i would have come accross it eventually and read it but he basically saved me heaps of time.  If this is still off-topic, apologies, but it can be closed now anyway.

Comment: you need to create your own rest API service. so you call the methods from external system using callout and pass the data from external system to salesforce. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_rest_1.htm

Comment: Thanks Ratan, yours was the first answer and was all the help i needed, had a working example going in 10 minutes.  : )

Answer (score 3):

All you need do is expose your apex method using simple rest api.
have a look at below code.

```
@ RestResource(urlMapping = '/CreateAccount/*')
 global class CreateAccountClass {

    @HttpGet
    global static void createAccountUsingName() {

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String accountName = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1); 
        Account a=new Account(name=Accountname);
        insert a;

        RestContext.response.responseBody=Blob.valueOf(a.id);


    }

 }
```

Here there is a webservice running at url
https://yoursfinstance/services/apexrest/CreateAccount/GreatBritainTrading

when you hit this endpoint after authorisation, you will see an new account is created and it will return you account id .

You can get great info about how to get authorization using the below links
http://kalyanlanka.blogspot.in/2014/08/calling-apex-rest-service-using-postman.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm

Comment: Thanks for this susanoo, thanks for the links.  Ratan's answer was enough but thankyou for your answer also.   Your 1st link does not work but it may be a firewall or other issue at my end.

Comment: First link means your salesforce org instance like cs31.salesforce.com or ap4.salesfroce.com /the conituned link.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways:

REST API: Explained in detail by Susanoo. This is preferred and is more secure as it requires authorization.

There is another way to invoke an Apex Class without any authorization. This method requires you to expose a Visualforce page on a force.com site. The page will accept a list of parameters via the URL and then the controller will work as per your logic based on the parameters passed. You will have to provide access to the guest user to the relevant data. Few points to consider here

- There is no authorization required and hence you risk exposing data and the operation to anyone with access to the URL.
- You can restrict the access to URL to specific IP addresses via the profile of the guest user.
- For extra security, you can add another parameter that would a key only you would know to how decrypt and it can change per day (basically it uses date as an parameter to encrypt and decrypt).

Comment: Exposing a Page on force.com site will always create records using Guest SIte uSer context. Which is not always correct as multiple users accessing will be using same user.

The method Rajesh Suggested is called as Webhooks. The limit here is bandwidth and server time. Some 30-40 mins of server time can be used while redendering a page on force.com site, if huge amout of processing needs to be done, better avoid this webhook approch.

Comment: @susanoochidori Thanks for adding that; missed them. This is a method that should be used only in very rare cases and with extreme caution.